# Swift 2.1 Dictionary extension

Tags: ios, swift, macos, dictionary

I'm hoping to write a Swift dictionary extension that will append the reliably same data that eventually gets passed into a web request as URL params. I've tried various tricks, none seem to work.

The closest i've gotten is:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    mutating func auth() -> Dictionary  {
        self.updateValue("2.0", forKey: "api")
        return self
    }
}
```

But this is still throwing the error:

> Cannot invoke 'updateValue' with an argument list of type '(String,
>   forKey:String)'

on the line that reads, "self.updateValue(..."

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `self.updateValue("2.0" as StringLiteralConvertible, forKey: "api" as AnyObject )` help? I think its a type mismatch but I'm away from the office mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to cast your string as! Value or as! Key. Also you have declared your method as mutating so you don't need to return anything.

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func auth()  {
        updateValue("2.0" as! Value, forKey: "api" as! Key)
    }
}

var dic: [String:AnyObject] = [:]

print(dic)  // "[:]\n"
dic.auth()
print(dic)  // "["api": 2.0]\n"
```